# Vector of fixed array in c++98

Tags: c++, c++98

I need to store an indeterminable number of triangles in a vector, therefore, it would be something like:

```
std::vector<Point[3]>
```

But that is not valid C++98. What are other solutions that do not involve a triangle struct?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not use a struct?

Comment: I'd create a new type Triangle that holds the 3 points, personally, and store that in the vector.

Comment: Check if your compiler comes with `<tr1/array>`...

Comment: This is a duplicate of ["Pushing a static array into a std::vector?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191535/pushing-a-static-array-into-a-stdvector) asked by none other than yourself.  It's good to see that our help has been useful to you and that you've learned from having asked so many questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You may define a `struct`
- You may use `pair<pair<Point,Point>,Point>` type
- If you can use latest C++, there are many options and one of them is using `std::tuple`. If there are more of such cases, you may implement your own `tuple` class taking 3 or more types.

Comment: `pair<pair<Point,Point>,Point>` - please, no, no, no!

Comment: That depends on perspective. I know it would be complex to understand what `.first.second` would mean in such case. That's why I suggested `tuple`.

Comment: Although I would never use a pair of pair point, and I was aware of tuple, and making a struct, I will accept your answer because you did not play it safe and go straight to boost :)

Answer (score 5):

Try a `boost::array<Point, 3>`. That should do the necessities.

Comment: @Ajay I think boost is designed to conform to C++ 98

Comment: Yes, but the implementation of `array` - Probably that will work. But not sure if compiler would support all of complicated template stuff.

Comment: @Ajay: Any compiler that can compile `std::vector` can compile `boost::array`.

Comment: I do understand. But I don't know since when `boost::array` was in Boost library. It means if I get latest Boost, it may or may not compile on all compilers. May be Boost libraries are smart enough to enable/disable features depending on compiler version - but which compiler? That would/might break the portability.

Comment: @Ajay: Boost goes to great lengths to remain portable, and `array` is a trivial template.

Comment: I don't agree. VC6 couldn't compile most of template stuff, and Boost uses complicated template magic.

Comment: @Ajay: `array` is a very, very trivial class template. Any compiler which has the necessary wherewithall to compile `std::vector` can handle `boost::array`. `array` does not use any complicated template magic, at all. Boost does have some such, but you need to actually know where it is. Furthermore, Boost has macros for telling you what compiler you're on so that you can have code that compiles for that compiler. Besides, if you're running VC6, then you seriously have to upgrade anyway.